# Understanding code for concatenating files in Python?

Tags: python

I need to concatenate a few large files in Python, and came across a helpful snippet of code here, but am having trouble understanding a small part of it. Here is the code:

```
filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', ...]
     with open('path/to/output/file', 'w') as outfile:
          for fname in filenames:
               with open(fname) as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                         outfile.write(line)
```

The only thing I don't understand is what the 'w' is supposed to represent, so it would be great if someone explained it. Thanks!

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file, you must specify a mode in which it will be opened. The character `'w'` stands for 'write', and it means that the file will be opened for writing, after it has been truncated.

Subsequent calls to `open()` in your code snippet (`with open(fname) as infile`) need not explicitly define a mode, since `'r'` (which stands for 'read') is the default mode used when calling `open()`. They are equivalent to writing:

```
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    # rest of code here
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for `open` for more details.